# MS-Access Get field value, run through VBA function, and send to SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

When calling functions from an SQL SELECT statement (Ex `SELECT doubLat("SELECT [Map index].[Latitude] FROM [Map index]") AS decLat FROM`...) how can you return the value of each item individually? I expect this is done more form the method (here in VBA) than the SQL itself.

Note that I am not referring to changing any field values in the database itself; the goal is simply to pass a modified version into SQL for further processing. The method I currently have is shown below.

```
Function doubLat(strSQL As String) As Double
    Dim db As Database
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Set db = CurrentDb

    If (strSQL <> "") Then
        Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
        For i = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1 'For each field in the recordset'
            If (rs.Fields(i).Name = "Latitude") Then
                doubLat = CDbl(LatToDecimal(rs.Fields(i).Value))
                MsgBox (doubLat) 'debug message'
            End If
        Next i
        rs.Close
    End If
End Function
```

LatToDecimal takes a DMS latitude value and returns a Decimal latitude value as a String. doubLat (shown above) serves as a wrapper to convert that String to a Double in order to perform further operations.

How can individual values retrieved from such a function be passed back to an SQL query and associated (preferably temporarily) with the records that generated them if the goal is to use this data in another function later in the query?

EDIT: Further information about the query below.

`SELECT`...`[Map index].[Map_Date], doubLat("SELECT [Map index].[Latitude] FROM [Map index]") AS decLat`
`FROM [Map index]` `WHERE`...`AND (decLat BETWEEN 39 AND 41)`

The last condition shown (`decLat BETWEEN 39 AND 41`) is to eventually be replaced with a conditional using the haversine function and a user-defined distance.

An example of what I am attempting to do is [here](http://sqlexamples.info/SQL/inlineudf.htm), with the caveat that I need to access the "new" data (output) later in the query.

Current doubLat function is [here](http://pastebin.com/Lv6ZyRX7). (Edit: Error caused by lack of `rs.MoveNext` has since been corrected.)

Final Results: As suspected, the solution was fairly simple. The `SELECT` statement needed to call `doubLat([Map index].[Latitude]) AS decLat`, where doubLat is as shown below.

```
Function doubLat(ByVal latIn As String) As Double
    Dim newLat As Double
    newLat = CDbl(LatToDecimal(latIn))
    doubLat = newLat
End Function
```

Note that this solution does not yet account properly for null values in `[Map index].[Latitude]` and will set `decLat` to `#Error` for those records.

Comment: Using a unique identifier? I am not able to understand your problem clearly. Could you explain in simple English without any technology jargon, maybe using some examples what is that you want?

Comment: I have a database containing a Latitude field. I want to use the content of that field as part of my query, but need to reformat it first. (Because it is in DMS, and I need Decimal for another function.)

Comment: just wrap it inside another select: make a select query where you transform and do all the needed stuff, but leave the condition `decLat BETWEEN 39 AND 41` out. then create a second select in which you select `FROM` the previous select and now use the condition `decLat BETWEEN 39 AND 41`. Instead of `SELECT stuff FROM ... WHERE ... AND declat...` do something like `SELECT t.* FROM (SELECT stuff FROM ... WHERE ...) AS t WHERE declat...`

Answer (score 1):

rs.fields("Lattitude").value will give you the contents of that field - is that what you mean?  As far as associating it with a specific record, I usually have a loop something like

```
set rs= ...
rs.movefirst
do while not rs.eof 
   ...
   Lattidue=rs.fields("Lattitude").value
   ...
   rs.movenext
   loop
```

This deals with one record of the recordset at a time, so you can associate the Lattitude to any other fields of the same record

Comment: That definitely is a more efficient way of retrieving the field content in VBA, but I suppose I didn't phrase the question clearly enough; how can I use the converted value (the output of the function) later in my query? I'm currently attempting luk2302's wrapper method.

Comment: Further, I am attempting to get the value from this function and pass it back to the query, as [here](http://sqlexamples.info/SQL/inlineudf.htm).

Comment: Can you clarify the question?  Once you have Lattitude, or in you code above, doubLat, what do you want to do with that?  Once you have the value in  a variable, you should be able to use that variable later in the script.  Just for a simple example, you can display it with Msgbox ("Lattitude: " & Lattitude & "; converted: " & doubLat).

Comment: The problem is that I need to pass each value individually back the the query (SQL) itself; I'm not trying to do anything with them in the VBA script except return the value. The code you posted doesn't seem to work for that, as any attempt at opening the query (which calls doubLat) now causes Access to stop responding. I've added a link to the full current code of doubLat in the question.

Comment: OK, I misunderstood - you have a function to convert from Lattitude to DoubLat that you want to use in a query.  I think you need to have a single output from the function, not multiple records (although I'm not sure).  So you need to get the selection criteria inside the function - possibly as another argument or as part of the SQL string.  Will your WHERE clause get you a unique record from the table?

Comment: Another simpler approach is to write a query to convert Lattitude to DoubLat for all the records in the table (just create a query field with "doubLat:CDbl(LatToDecimal(rs.Fields(i).Value))" in it, and use this query as the input to the next query.  Then you have all the original fields and the calculated field for each record.

Comment: I figured I would need a single output, since the SQL seems to require a return value. `strSQL` was meant to bring the criteria in; that's why it's used as a parameter for `rs.OpenRecordset`. The full WHERE clause will not return a unique record. (The freeze mentioned in the last comment was because I had forgotten to MoveNext. It has since been fixed, and decLat now has a value, but it is always the same one.)

Comment: I may be looking in the wrong place, but when I put that `doubLat:...` line as a Field in my query (design view) I get an error stating that there may be an invalid period or parentheses, highlighting the dot in `Fields("Latitude").Value`. (`i` replaced with `"Latitude"` because I'm not sure where the `i` is coming from.) EDIT: `Expr1: doubLat([Latitude])` is also nonfunctional, stating that the expression is typed incorrectly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78936/discussion-between-don-george-and-nathaniel-bendinsky).

Comment: sorry - try DoubLat:cdbl(LatToDecimal(lattitude)).  The other syntax was for the script and the recordset, and I forgot to change it to work in the query.